# UiTableviewcell with UITextView auto layout scroll

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

I used `UITextView` in `UITableviewCell` which can edit and expand the height. Everything is working fine with auto layout, textview and tableviewcell that expand height automatically.

My problem is when the height expand beyond screen size and when keyboard show. When I enter new line in textview I can't see the cursor (because the height beyond the visible view) and didn't scroll automatically. Other scenario is when the textview height is beyond the screen size, when I edit the text in middle place, the scroll doesn't work properly.

My idea is I would like to develop like  Facebook post view controller or email compose view controller (like multiple different `uitableviewcell` and some of the textview can expand the height)

Comment: Found the solution :)